# "olympic champions" vs. "champions of the olympics"

Tags: word-usage

[Ngram Viewer](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=champions+of+the+olympics%2Colympic+champions%2Cchampions+in+the+olympics%2Cchampions+for+the+olympics&year_start=1800&corpus=26&smoothing=3&year_end=2019&direct_url=t1%3B%2Colympic%20champions%3B%2Cc0) shows "olympic champions" is common while other possibilities are zero.

[image]

Note: "other possibilities" refers to champions of the olympics,champions in the olympics,champions for the olympics

Comment: This isn't a question.

Answer (score 0):

This is because if you win a gold medal, you aren't "champion of the Olympics", you're only champion of that particular event at the Olympics. I.e., you can be the Olympic 100-meter dash champion, or the Olympic 200-meter freestyle swimming champion, but there is no single champion of the whole Olympic games.

Also, it's at least equally common to talk about "Olympic medalists" (which would include 2nd and 3rd-place finishers) or "Olympic gold medalists" as to talk about "Olympic champions".